# Cannot resolve getSupportFragmentManager() in adapter

Tags: android, fragment, adapter, android-dialogfragment

I've this adapter, but there's this kind of issue:

> Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

The Fragment is a DialogFragment and the class extends AppCompatDialogFragment
Could i start this Fragment in other way? Or is there a solution?

```
public class PostAdapterProfile extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReferences;
SharedPreferences prefs;
private String uuid;
private boolean verifyStar;
private User currentUserPost;

public PostAdapterProfile(@NonNull Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<Post> objects) {
    super(context, resourceId, objects);
    resource = resourceId;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Inflating view");
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_element, null);
    }

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReferences = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(v.getContext());
    uuid = prefs.getString("RECORDMAN1", "");
    CurrentUser c = (CurrentUser)getContext().getApplicationContext();
    currentUserPost = c.getUserPost();

    final Post p = getItem(position);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("postId", p.getId());

    Log.d("DEBUG", "contact c=" + p);
    final Button nameButton;
    TextView testoView, dataView;
    ImageView profile_pic;
    final ImageView imagePost;
    final Button likeButtonGrey, likeButtonOk, numberLike, commentaButton;// redHeart, blackHeart;
    ImageButton xButton;

    xButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    xButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    xButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.x);
    xButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentEliminaPost fragmentEliminaPost = new FragmentEliminaPost();
            fragmentEliminaPost.show(manager, "ahahahaha");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is method of `AppCompatActivity` not `ArrayAdapter`.
If you want to use it you can use it by activity context . for your case .

```
  ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `getSupportFragmentManager();` is not a method of `ArrayAdapter`. You can only call it from an Activity or a Fragment. I would not recommend swapping fragments directly from the Adapter. That logic should be done elsewhere.

E.g. Call back to your fragment and do the work there:

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
        ((MyActivityOrFragment)context).myMethod()
    }
```

... then in the fragment/activity

```
public void myMethod(){

 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentEliminaPost fragmentEliminaPost = new FragmentEliminaPost();
        fragmentEliminaPost.show(manager, "ahahahaha");

}
```